# How can I set the transform value extra display in Photoshop to display whole pixels

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How can I set the extras displayed when transforming to use whole pixels as the measurement?

[image: pic]

Comment: What version number of Photoshop are you using? You might want to edit that into your question.

Comment: @kontur, Adobe Photoshop Version: 13.1.2 Version: 6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the preferences....

[image: prefs]

Or you can Control/Right-Click a ruler and choose Pixels there.

[image: ruler]

### Edit:

The heads up display (HUD) used for the transform values will always show the exact location in the document. You can't adjust the HUD to only display whole numbers.

You can set things up to snap to every pixel if that's helpful.

In the Preferences, under Guides & Grids set it to a **Gridline every 1 pixel** and then use **View > Extras > Show Grid**. And then ensure **View > Snap to > Grid** is checked. This will allow you to snap to whole pixels.

Comment: ty for edit, but I want my pixels to be integer values

Comment: @SakerONE You mean you want only whole pixel values?? If that's the case, in the Preferences, under Guides & Grids set it to a Gridline every 1 pixel and then use View > Extras > Show Grid. This will allow you to snap to whole pixels, but the floating HUD will always show your exact location.

Comment: Yes, whole) Sorry)